# How to retrieve the detailedText from a cell then use it in a function?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiapplication

I'm trying to retrieve the detailedText contained in a UITableView Cell (which is a phone number "String") and then Use it in a function that will make a phone call.

- **Problem:**

  My app keeps crashing with the error **"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value "**
  even though there is a value inside the variable.

I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong with force unwrapping the optional

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
   let getPhone = cell?.detailTextLabel?.text

   if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0 {
  
     if let phoneNumber = getPhone{
       openPhoneApp(phoneNumber)
     }
}

// Open Phone App
func openPhoneApp(phoneNum: String){
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "tel:\(phoneNum)")!)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Put a break point at at the start of your function, and check each property if I'ts nil.

Comment: The only force unwrap I see is in the NSURL, so you're probably creating a badly formed URL.
BTW: DON'T force unwrap things

Comment: Xcode is suggesting to unwrap it : "Value of optional type ' NSURL?' not unwrapped"

Comment: I am assuming since you are using a UITableView so you have  an array to populate your data, so what don't you retrieve that data at that indexPath straight from your array or data structure

Comment: Unwrap it with a nice `if let` or `guard` statement.

Comment: at error program stops just go to line where it stops and read it letter by letter, you can do that

Comment: @Lu_ the error message is written in the question

Comment: @AziCode i'm talking about line the message appears not the message. Show us the screenshot where you get the error and we can see the line where it is please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use force unwrapping if you're not 100% sure it can be unwrapped. And avoid it if possible even then!

Your `openPhoneApp` function must receive a non-nil string, so everything's ok up to that moment.

Try to replace your force unwrap with something like this:

```
func openPhoneApp(phoneNum: String) {
    guard let url = NSURL(string: "tel:\(phoneNum)") else {
        print("badly formed telephone url")
        return
    }
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
}
```

---

Although I'd argue that your function's name implies that it WILL open the phone app, so maybe you should just go and ask for a correctly formed URL, like this:

```
func openPhoneApp(phoneURL: NSURL) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(phoneURL)
}
```

and check for that kind of stuff before even calling it:

```
if let phone = getPhone, phoneURL = NSURL(string: "tel:\(phone)") {
    openPhoneApp(phoneURL)
}
```

Comment: Yes, the phone numbers that I was retrieving from the cell were formated  like this "(510) 222 2222".
So now I'm getting rid of the spaces between numbers, and I'm also getting rid of the two parentheses around the (510) before calling "openPhoneApp".

Answer (score 1):

Did you checked the value of phoneNumber variable? it could be nil.

You can check this answer: I think this will solve your problem.

[What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

specifically this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35683816/5660422

Comment: phoneNumber is not nil, it contains the string that I want to use

Answer (score 1):

Please use tel:// scheme and always call

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL
```

before

Comment: I don't want to use textLabel since it's just a title, I need to retrieve detailTextLabel which contains the phone number that I want to use